# math.h - Cannot compile Code with log() and rand() function

Tags: c

When i compile the following code snippet I get this error message from my compiler:

```
/tmp/ccT1yBa1.o: In function `main':
test.c:(.text.startup+0x34): undefined reference to `log'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

_

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <math.h>

void main(){

srand(time(NULL));
double r1 = (rand() % 1000)/1000.0;
double r2 = log(r1);
printf("%lf\n",r2);

}
```

Compiled with

```
gcc -O2 test.c
```

What's wrong?

Comment: You need [-lm after the source file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19372317/c-failing-to-compile-cant-find-math-h-functions/19372412#19372412)

Answer (score 2):

You have forgot the `-lm` to link with the math library.

```
gcc -O2 test.c -lm
```