# How to compile the exp bechmark in riscv-test

Tags: gcc, riscv

I have built simple program to calculate the exp of value. I got error;

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include "util.h"
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {               
 double value = -150;
    Start_Timer();
    for(int i=0; i<500 ;i++){
    result = exp(value);    
    value++;
}
    Stop_Timer();
  User_Time=End_Time-Begin_Time;
  printf("User_Time: %ld  - %ld =  %ld - \n", End_Time,Begin_Time,User_Time);
   printf("The Exponential of %ld is %ld\n", value, result);
    return 0;

}
```

Any idea how to use exp in Benchmark for testing.
i have figured out that exp function need -x and -lm for compiling. How can i use them in the test
[C Failing to compile: Can't find math.h functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19372317/c-failing-to-compile-cant-find-math-h-functions)

I tried to edit the makefile in riscv-test/benchmark but i think , it is little bit tricky for me.

Error Message:https://github.com/riscv/riscv-tests/issues/142

Comment: error Message is : https://github.com/riscv/riscv-tests/issues/142

Comment: I have solved this issue by using maths libraries available on git-hub. Place the exp.c in common folder.